# StartUp Disk Creator always crash at the end of process

Tags: startup-disk-creator

Without persistent storage, it will crash when creating boot loader, couple of seconds after I input my password, and with persistent storage, it always crash at 99%, no matter how much space for persistent storage defined. How to solve this?

Same result for 12.10 and 13.04.

Comment: sounds like this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/859539 for which the semi-effective workaround is to launnch the usb creator from terminal using `sudo usb-creator-gtk --allow-system-internal`

Comment: Check out the bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/859539) as suggested by amc.  If this is the same problem you have select "Affects me too" as the more people a bug affects the more priority the developers will give to fixing it,

Comment: This question is **definitely not off-topic**. I'm getting the same error always on _Ubuntu 13.10_ (stable version, all updates). The workaround of @amc worked for me too! I could create a working, bootable Live-Ubuntu on an USB device, after starting the start-up disk creator with `sudo usb-creator-gtk --allow-system-internal`.

Comment: For anyone else with the same issue, today on Ubuntu 12.10: Startup Disk Creator always crashes as described. `sudo usb-creator-gtk --allow-system-internal` crashes too. Unetbootin worked once I managed to install 7zip; Software Center and apt-get said there was no installation candidate. Did manual download of the [deb package](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/utopic/universe/base/p7zip-full) instead. (Download deb package, double click to install.)

Comment: This is not off topic.

Comment: This is not a bug report and not for development version.

Comment: I agree. This also happens on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (64 bit), so it's definitely not just for a development version, 14.04 LTS is still supported!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all make sure that the downloaded ISO is OK.  Do an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on it to verify.  Make sure that you USB drive is formtted with fat 32.  Then try using a different program to create you USB.

Some of the programs that you can use to create your USB [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [Live USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/liveusb-install-live-usb-creator/).  If you're running windows, you can use [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Comment: The downloaded ISO is ok, I'm able to make bootable drive using Unetbootin with the ISO. Is this a bug? I remember clearly that until 11.10 Startup Disk Creator works fine in my system, not sure about 12.04, but it simply crash on 12.10 and 13.04.

Comment: I'm not aware of any bug.  I've tried start-up disk creator, just a few minutes ago, and it worked.  Well If this answered your question, you may mark this answer as accepted:)

Comment: I think this answer is alternative, not the real solution. The question is about startup disk creator, but this answer suggest the similar apps like unetbooting and yumi.